# shapes.addpicture gives 1004 error

Tags: vba, excel

I have got a fairly simple sub, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
Sub Test()
Dim p as object
strpath = "http://www.someurl.com/sample.jpg" ' some jpg
Set p = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(strpath, False, False, 100, 100, 86, 129)
End Sub
```

When I do this it gives me runtime error 1004, specified value out of range. However, if I change the second "false" to "true", it works fine and inserts the picture. According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171535%28v=office.11%29.aspx) the second true/false affects whether the picture will be saved with the document. I would not like this to happen.

Anyone have any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
Sub sof20301212ShapesAddpicture()
  Dim strPath
  Dim p As Object
  strpath = "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"
  Set p = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(strPath, msoCTrue, msoTrue, 100, 100, 86, 129)
End Sub
```

Ref [Shapes.AddPicture method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.shapes.addpicture.ASPX?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1):

```
'Declaration
FunctionAddPicture ( _
  Filename As String, _
  LinkToFile As MsoTriState, _
  SaveWithDocument As MsoTriState, _
  LeftAsSingle, _
  TopAsSingle, _
  WidthAsSingle, _
  HeightAsSingle _
) AsShape


Filename: The file from which the OLE object is to be created.
LinkToFile: Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState
  The file to link to. Can be one of these MsoTriState constants:
  msoCTrue
  msoFalse To make the picture an independent copy of the file.
  msoTriStateMixed
  msoTriStateToggle
  msoTrue To link the picture to the file from which it was created.
SaveWithDocument
  Type: Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState
  Required MsoTriState. To save the picture with the document.
```

LinkToFile and SaveWithDocument cannot be both false, as nowhere to save image.

LinkToFile and SaveWithDocument pair can be:

```
 true, true
 true, false
 false, true
```

Comment: I've been looking for hours.  Your comment *LinkToFile and SaveWithDocument cannot be both false, as nowhere to save image,* was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would only like to add another possible reason and solution. I also got the Error 1004, specified value out of range.

I had object library enabled and all this stuff. Finally I realized that earlier in my code there is a line which locks the worksheet. After unlocking it everything worked fine.